# Cannot upgrade heroku stack from bamboo-mri-1.9.2 to heroku-20

Tags: heroku

I have an old neglected Heroku stack (bamboo-mri-1.9.2) that I now want to upgrade to Heroku-20. I know bamboo-mri-1.9.2 has long ago stopped being supported, but when I attempt to upgrade via the CLI I get this:

```
heroku stack:set heroku-20 -a my_app
Setting stack to heroku-20... !
 ▸    this stack migration path is not available.
```

Via the Heroku dashboard gets a similar result.

I cannot find anything within Heroku or on Google to help - what do I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out (via Heroku support) that you cannot upgrade from something this old, in this way.

You need to go through the process of creating a new Heroku app from within your original codebase.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack#manually-created-test-app

Go to the section 'Manually Created test App' and follow the instructions there.